# Divide Rows of DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, duplicates, sql-insert

I am inserting Records of an `Excel` Sheet in a table. Problem is Excel sheet contains rows that have `duplicate` values in some columns. But since I am reading the whole Excel in a `DataTable`, all these rows are loaded in my DataTable and therefore when I Insert into `SQL Table` I get duplicate records. Can anyone suggest any solution to this? How can I avoid this duplication. Should I have to break the DataTable in rows somehow?

C# Code: Reading Excel and Inserting rows in DataTable

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[42] { new DataColumn("Template", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Cust_Name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Invoice_No", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("InvoiceDate",typeof(DateTime)),
                new DataColumn("SR_No", typeof(int)),
                .
                .
                .
                new DataColumn("ContactTel3", typeof(string))});

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
            if (rowIndex > 0)
            {
                string Template = row.Cells[0].Text;
                string Cust_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;
                int Invoice_No = int.Parse(row.Cells[2].Text);
                //DateTime InvoiceDate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[3].Text, "d-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string InvoiceDate = (row.Cells[3].Text);
                int Sr_No = int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Text);
                .
                .
                .
                string ContactTel3 = (row.Cells[41].Text);
                dt.Rows.Add(Template, Cust_Name, Invoice_No, InvoiceDate, Sr_No, Description1, Description2, Description3, Description4, Description5,
                    CurrencyCode, Amount, Subject, Reference, CustomerAddress1, CustomerAddress2, CustomerAddress3, CustomerAddress4, CustomerAddress5,
                    CustomerAddress6, CustomerTelephone, EmailIdTo, EmailIdCC, BankName, AccountTitle, AccountNo, CurrencyCode1, BankAddress1,
                    BankAddress2, BankAddress3, BankAddress4, SwiftCode, IBAN, ContactName1, ContactEmail1, ContactTel1, ContactName2, ContactEmail2,
                       ContactTel2, ContactName3, ContactEmail3, ContactTel3);
            }
        }
```

C# Code for Passing DataTable to Stored Procedure

```
string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString);
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[spInsertExcel]"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblInvoice", dt);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
```

And Here's my Stored Procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertExcel]
@tblInvoice [tblInvoiceType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      IF NOT EXISTS(Select Invoice_No from Invoice)
      Begin
        INSERT into Invoice([Template],[Cust_Name],[Invoice_No] ,[InvoiceDate],[Sr_No] ,[CurrencyCode] ,[Subject] ,[Reference],[CustomerAddress1] ,
        [CustomerAddress2] ,[CustomerAddress3] ,[CustomerAddress4] ,[CustomerAddress5] ,[CustomerAddress6] ,[CustomerTelephone],[EmailIdTo] ,
        [EmailIDCC] ,[BankName] ,[AccountTitle] ,[AccountNo] ,[Bankcurrency] ,[BankAddress1] ,[BankAddress2] ,[BankAddress3] ,[BankAddress4] ,
        [SwiftCode],[IBAN],[ContactName1],[ContactEmail1],[ContactTel1],[ContactName2],[ContactEmail2],[ContactTel2],[ContactName3],[ContactEmail3],[ContactTel3])

        Select [Template],[Cust_Name],[Invoice_No],[InvoiceDate],Sr_No, 
        CurrencyCode,[Subject], Reference,CustomerAddress1,CustomerAddress2,CustomerAddress3,CustomerAddress4 ,
        CustomerAddress5,CustomerAddress6,CustomerTelephone,EmailIdTo , EmailIDCC,BankName, AccountTitle,
        AccountNo , Bankcurrency,BankAddress1,BankAddress2,BankAddress3,BankAddress4,SwiftCode,IBAN,ContactName1,ContactEmail1,ContactTel1,
        ContactName2 ,ContactEmail2,ContactTel2,ContactName3 ,ContactEmail3,ContactTel3 from @tblInvoice
    END
    Else
        Raiserror('You have already uploaded this file',16,1)
END
```

**EDITED**
As Answered by a user here, I included the following line of code

```
DataTable distinctDt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Template", "Cust_Name"...);
```

But still I get The same table. Attached Picture of distinctDt on Debug

[image]

I want to insert duplicate columns like `Template`,`Cust_Name`,`Invoice_No` etc in `Invoice` table and non-duplicate columns like `Amount`,`Description1` in another table.But this way `Invoice` table will have multiple records. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter similiar records after adding them into DataTable by calling Distinct method on DataRow collection:

```
var distinct = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Or you can filter them before adding to DataTable like this:

```
GridView1.Rows.Select(x=> new 
{
                Template = row.Cells[0].Text;
                Cust_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;
                Invoice_No = int.Parse(row.Cells[2].Text);
                InvoiceDate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[3].Text, "d-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                nvoiceDate = (row.Cells[3].Text);
                Sr_No = int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Text);
}).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select distinct values from your table `dt` before dumping it into database. Using code below.

```
DataTable distinctDt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Template", "Cust_Name"...);
```

Now use `distinctDt` to dump that distinct data into database.
For more information on this refer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are correct. but problem is, not all columns in the Excel Sheet contain same data for multiple rows so as expected this will give distinct rows. What I want is, to insert duplicated columns in `Invoice` table and non-duplicated columns for example `Amount` and `Description` in other table. Isn't there any way I can filter on bases of few columns rather than the whole table columns?

Comment: `ToTable` expects string column listing also, just mention only those `Amount` and `Description` columns there and you will get distinct `amount` and `description` values.

Comment: distinct will run on each column you are specifying inside `ToTable` method. In snip you provided in edit it's clear that `description1` is different for each row that is why they are getting pulled up.

Comment: Agree and Your solution is perfect in that sense.Perhaps I failed to post my question correctly so now I have Edited it to make clear what I actually want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a `IDENTITY` column in your `invoice` table.
If you add an `IDENTITY(1, 1)` field say it `ID` you can do your custom operation on it in an indexed way.
Now you can use another stored procedure to copy your data from `invoice` table to `otherTable` like this:

```
INSERT INTO [otherTable]
SELECT 
    [Amount], [Description]
FROM
    [invoice]
GROUP BY
    [Amount], [Description]
```